# Creating a Binary Search Tree from a sorted array

Tags: binary-search-tree

I am currently checking about coding an algorithms. If we have the following case:

Given a sorted (increasing order) array with unique integer elements, wrote an algorithm to create a binary search tree with minimal height.

The following code is proposed as the solution:

```
TreeNode createMinimalBST(int arr[], int start, int end){
    if (end < start) {
        return null;
    }
    int mid = (start + end) / 2;
    TreeNode n = new TreeNode(arr[mid]);
    n.setLeftChild(createMinimalBST(arr, start, mid - 1));
    n.setRightChild(createMinimalBST(arr, mid + 1, end));
    return n;
}

TreeNode createMinimalBST(int array[]) {
    return createMinimalBST(array, 0, array.length - 1);
}
```

But if I try this code with the following array input:

[2,4,6,8,10,20]

And I perform the first iteration

```
createMinimalBST([2,4,6,8,10,20], 0, 5);
```

The following line:

```
int mid = (start + end) / 2; // in Java (0 + 5) / 2  =  2;
```

would calculate the mid as the root of the binary search tree the position number 2 which is the value 6.

However, the binary search tree in this example should look like:

```
    8
   / \
  4   10
 / \    \
2   6   20
```

The code is coming from a reputable source, but my gut feeling is that the implementation is incorrect.

Am I missing something or the implementation is not right ?

Comment: end should be the length of your array. is it?

Comment: the value of end is correct in the code (according to the solution provided) `array.length - 1`

Comment: You can modify the formula to calculate `mid`. If `end-start+1` is odd, the `mid = (start+end)/2`, otherwise `mid = (start + end)/2 + 1`. Moreover, can you please share the link of the source ?

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS The source is a book called Cracking the Coding Interview (6th edition). The solution is on page 242.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Reference [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/)

**Algorithm** -

1. Get the Middle of the array and make it root.
2. Recursively do same for left half and right half.

   - Get the middle of left half and make it left child of the root
                  created in step 1.
   - Get the middle of right half and make it right child of the
                    root created in step 1.

[Wikipedia Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree)

**CODE**

```
 class Node {

    int data;
    Node left, right;

    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        left = right = null;
    }
}

class BinaryTree {

    static Node root;

    /* A function that constructs Balanced Binary Search Tree 
    from a sorted array */
    Node sortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {

        /* Base Case */
        if (start > end) {
            return null;
        }

        /* Get the middle element and make it root */
        int mid = (start + end) / 2;
        Node node = new Node(arr[mid]);

        /* Recursively construct the left subtree and make it
        left child of root */
        node.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr, start, mid - 1);

        /* Recursively construct the right subtree and make it
        right child of root */
        node.right = sortedArrayToBST(arr, mid + 1, end);

        return node;
    }

    /* A utility function to print preorder traversal of BST */
    void preOrder(Node node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        System.out.print(node.data + " ");
        preOrder(node.left);
        preOrder(node.right);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BinaryTree tree = new BinaryTree();
        int arr[] = new int[]{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12};
        int n = arr.length;
        root = tree.sortedArrayToBST(arr, 0, n - 1);
        System.out.println("Preorder traversal of constructed BST");
        tree.preOrder(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response but I believe that the code is still picking up 6 as the root of the tree rather than 8. If the root starts by 6 it is not a `binary search tree`

Comment: @Tk421 **If the root starts by 6 it is not a binary search tree**- that's incorrect. It will be a **balanced binary search** irrespective of the fact that the root is 6 or 8.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS I have double checked and it works. There are several binary search tree that can be generated. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to remove the pre order traversal after copy-pasting from [GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorted-array-to-balanced-bst/). -1 for not attributing your source.

Comment: Wrote this answer way back; at that point of time I didn't realize the importance of giving credits to folks, but now i do; added the reference and thanks for the heads up

Answer (score 2):

A sorted array will give you a balanced binary tree. This could be done easily in O(n) time, as we can get the middle element in O(1) time. Following is a simple algorithm,

> 1. Construct a node for the middle element in the array and return it (this will be the root in the base case).
>
>    2. Repeat from 1. on the left half of the array, assigning the return value to the left child of the root.
>    3. Repeat from 1. on the right half of the array, assigning the return value to the right child of the root.

**Java implementation**

```
 TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int arr[], int start, int end) {  
           if (start > end)
              return null; // same as (start+end)/2, avoids overflow.    
           int mid = start + (end - start) / 2;      
           TreeNode node = new
           TreeNode(arr[mid]); 
           node.left = sortedArrayToBST(arr, start, mid-1); 
           node.right = sortedArrayToBST(arr, mid+1, end); 
            return node; 
    }
```

> TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int arr[]) {   return sortedArrayToBST(arr,
>   0, arr.length-1);  }

**Time Complexity:** ** *O(n)* **
Following is the recurrance relation for sortedArrayToBST().

> T(n) = 2T(n/2) + C
>
> T(n) --> Time taken for an array of size n
>
> C --> Constant (Finding middle of array and linking root to left and right
>   subtrees take constant time)

Comment: You gave two answers and both of them are same.

Comment: Not able to delete it. Will remove.

Comment: @GAURANGVYAS if u can you delete the other 2, please do.

Answer (score 0):

- get the `middle` of the array and make it as `root`
- recursively do the same for the left half and the right half

  - get the `middle` of the left half and make it the `left child` of the root
  - get the `middle` of the right half and make it the `right child` of the root

[image]

```cs
    public TreeNode Convert(int[] array)
    {
        if (array == null || array.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return Convert(array, 0, array.Length - 1);
    }

    private static TreeNode Convert(int[] array, int lo, int hi)
    {
        if (lo > hi)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        var root = new TreeNode(array[mid]);
        root.Left = Convert(array, lo, mid - 1);
        root.Right = Convert(array, mid + 1, hi);
        return root;
    }
```

**Time Complexity**: `O(n)`

from [CodeStandard](https://codestandard.net/articles/convert-sorted-array-into-a-binary-search-tree/)